# Redirect https non www to https www not working virtualhost

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost

I have this configuration in virtualhost for redirect https non www to https www but this configuration is not working

So when I visit `https://myweb.com/` it not redirect to `https://www.myweb.com/`

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

.... so on ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Is something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myweb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.